# Using substring to remove characters from a dynamic variable

Tags: php, wordpress, substring

I am trying to use substr to remove 4 characters from a URL string. The goal is to remove .jpg from the string and replace it with "-220x124.jpg".

I am using a wordpress plugin, advanced custom fields, but that is not the issue here. The issue is that the subst is not working with the Advanced custom fields code, the_sub_field. It returns the entire URL string without the last 4 characters removed. Any idea why?

Code below:

```
<?php if(get_field('still_uploads')): ?>
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php while(the_repeater_field('still_uploads') && $i <= 0 ): ?>

    <?php 
        $imagejesse =  the_sub_field('still_image');
        $imagejessenew = substr($imagejesse,0,-4); 
    ?>

    <?php echo $imagejessenew.'-220x124.jpg'; ?>
    <?php $i++ ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can see an example here:  http://gicreative-dev.com/blog/genre/gay/

Comment: Is there a reason why you put nearly every single line of code into its own <?php ... ?> tags?

Comment: I think the problem is with the dynamic variable. Is there any way to print the variable, and save it as a new variable so it can be modified with substr?

Comment: @bkconrad, yes I did, and it returns the URL string

Comment: @ ZombieHunter, no reason, I will put it in one php tag to clean it up

Comment: @JCHASE11: Are you sure there is no white space and newlines at the end? Use `var_dump()` instead of `echo`. If I look at the source code there are lot of tabs between the original URL and the appended string...

Comment: First, I don't see any dynamic variables (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in that script. Second, `$x = $y` automatically creates a copy of it.

Comment: @ZombieHunter, you are right, it does return some extra space. Is there a good way of removing any extra space from the string so it can be used with substr?

Comment: @JCHASE11: [trim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: `$imagejessenew = substr(trim($imagejesse),0,-4);`

Comment: It doesn't even look like it is outputting any <img> either which it looks like you may want with what you are trying to achieve. Also, it looks like something that may be better handled by just enabling post feature images and putting these images there.

Comment: @ckaufman, your probably right...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtr()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) like that:

```
$imagejessenew = strtr($imagejesse, array(
    '.jpg' => '-220x124.jpg',
));
```

See this for a proof: http://ideone.com/B8ZQe

Comment: I just updated it with no luck. See above link, its updated but with the same problem

Comment: I doubt this would help if `substr()` isn't returning the expected value either

Comment: @bkconrad: Please check it again - the second argument needs to be associative array, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, it works as expected. But OP's problem was trailing whitespace, not improper string manipulation (per se) :)

Comment: it works great if you type in the URL string, but when it is dynamically delivered via the_sub_field('still_image') it doesnt work, most likely because of the extra space. Perhaps using trim will fix it?

Comment: @Tadeck: Your right, but it doesn't matter, because if strtr() works, substr() works too: http://ideone.com/kjuJ1

Comment: @bkconrad: You are probably right, and it seems no one has solved the original problem (the issue with the string being not what you expect). I believe then that the question title should be changed, and its content should be updated to list `var_dump(the_sub_field('still_image'))` results within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $imagejessenew = substr(trim(the_sub_field('still_image')),0,-4);

    if($imagejessenew !== FALSE)
    {
        $imagejessenew .= '-220x124.jpg';
    }
    else
    {
        // Shit happened, the_sub_field('still_image') was shorter than 4 characters
    }
?>
```

Comment: @JCHASE11: Then use `var_dump(the_sub_field('still_image'))` before doing anything and check for the output in the source code.

Comment: it returns "http://gicreative-dev.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Buffering1.jpgNULL"

Comment: @JCHASE11: I think it returns "NULL" and that's the reason why substr() and all the rest is not working. Make sure you use the right value that represents your image URL.

Comment: yes, looks like I have to figure out a different solution, like using featured images...thanks for all the help

Comment: @JCHASE11: Well, some code is currently writing the actual image URL, so check for that piece of code and use it to generate your custom URL.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I am actually just going to move to a much different solution as I cannot seem to figure this out. The URL string is being generated, but for some reason its stubborn and will not modify from all these fixes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$imagejessenew = preg_replace('/(.*)(.(jpg|png|gif))$/i', '$1-220x124.$3', trim($imagejesse));
```

Comment: another great shot, but its of course not working. Thanks anyways

Comment: Try the slightly revised version.

Comment: tried, with the same results :( I am actually going to use a different solution to make this problem much easier to solve.